# Laravel 5.4 npm run dev error: Error: Cannot find module 'lodash._baseclone'

Tags: laravel, npm

I am trying to run following command: npm run dev. However, it is giving an error as

```
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

module.js:471
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'lodash._baseclone'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/korsall-clean/node_modules/node-
notifier/node_modules/lodash.clonedeep/index.js:9:17)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development 
node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --
config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely 
additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/.npm/_logs/2017-06-07T10_34_11_411Z-
debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely 
additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/.npm/_logs/2017-06-07T10_34_11_426Z-
debug.log
```

I have removed node_modules folder and re-installed it, but still it is giving same error.

Please guide me wher

Comment: is `lodash` library installed?

Answer (score 1):

There is a very similar error that I found in this thread: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/7221#issuecomment-226595754

There is a comment there that says the problem is related to the windows max path limitation of 260 characters. I tend to believe this is correct since I know I don't have the problem on my device that has the long paths enabled in windows - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation
I'm getting the crash on my build server which is running another version of windows.

Comment: I am not getting...how it is related?

Answer (score 0):

Try this npm i --save lodash._baseclone

Comment: After running above command, it gives error for other module in lodash...everything was working properly but all of a sudden it is giving errors of lodash...